# Set value for input which is source of onchange event in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5, asp.net-blazor

In Blazor Server App / .NET 6 preview 4 (same for .NET 5) I would like to handle onchange event and in certain cases to dismiss user input with setting a certain value to the textbox. There is a basic code for demonstation:

```
<input value="@tester" @onchange="@OnChangeHandler" />

@code {

    public string tester { get; set; }

    public void OnChangeHandler(ChangeEventArgs obj)
    {
        tester = "100";
    }
}
```

For some reason **input** shows "100" only once even though the property `tester` is set each time when `OnChangeHandler` fired. **input** keeps a value entered by the user ignoring the fact that `tester` is set to "100" when `onchange` occurs second and third time. How can I make **input** always contain actual value of `tester`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick dirty workaround would be something like this :

```
  public async Task OnChangeHandler(ChangeEventArgs obj)
    {
        tester =null;
        await Task.Delay(1); 
        tester = "100";
    }
```

it's not good a fix is planned in the preview 5 of dotnet6

Comment: this works, thanks! Could you provide a link please which refers to the plans to fix this? github issue for example.